# Having pp, have pp sentence

Tags: perfect-aspect, participles, construction

I'd like to ask questions about the exact tense of participial construction like the following sentence.

> Having worked in the industry over the years, I have sometimes been surprised to see young workers have worked punctually while their bosses have worked too late.

Q. Which one is correct among the following paraphrases?

> 1. **While I** **have worked** in the industry for the years, I have sometimes been ...
> 2. **While I** **worked** in the industry over the years, I have sometimes been ...
> 3. **As I worked** in the industry over the years, I have sometimes been ...

I would like to know the exact tense of participle when rephrasing the subordinate clause or adverbial clause.

"While I have worked in the industry over the years, I have frequently seen that lower-level employees haven't stayed as late as their bosses have done [so is needed here or not?]."

1. Working in the industry over the years, I have frequently seen that lower-level employees haven't stayed as late as their bosses have done.
2. Having worked in the industry over the years, I have frequently seen that lower-level employees haven't stayed as late as their bosses have done.

Comment: Are you just trying to say that you’ve seen lower-level employees who don’t stay as late as their bosses do?

Comment: Or possibly you are trying to say that the workers arrived punctually while their bosses arrived late...?

Comment: Having worked in the industry over the years, I have sometimes been surprised  = the same thing as: As I have worked. "while" introduces a slightly different idea.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,'While working in the industry...' would be more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean
''Having worked in the industry for years, I have noticed younger workers working punctually while their bosses usually come in late.'''

among the following paraphrases

1. 'While I have worked in the industry for the years' emphasized a regular remark you are about to make being valid. So ''sometimes'' isn't the best fit. Always or usually fits better. But WHILE, implies you are gong to talk about something other than this industry!

   2. In 'While I worked in the industry over the years, I have sometimes been ...' WHILE is totally unnecessary. ''Working in the industry for several years .... I notice'' is good.
2. ''As I worked in the industry over the years, I have sometimes been ..''
   This is the most awkward. 
   ''During my work over the years in this industry...'' would work.

But if the observation is only ''sometimes'' and not ''usually'' or 'always'' the need to state the years of experience to back it up, is not really necessary.